# Stop DIV containers from losing their size when content is added within them

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a web page with three sections, they should always fill the height of whatever display they're on and not resize.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
      font-size: 1em; 
}

.white {
    background-color: white;
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
} 

.orange {
    background-color: orange;
 height: 45%;
 width: 100%;
} 

.green {
    background-color: green;
 height: 45%;
 width: 100%;
} 
</style>

<div class="white">
<img class="welcome" src="" width="5%" height="5%" alt="Welcome">
</div>

<div class="orange">
<p>Welcome!</p>
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none">
    <img class="launch" src="" width="5%" height="5%" alt="Logo1">
</div>

<div class="green">
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none">
    <img class="launch" src="" width="5%" height="5%" alt="Logo2">
</div>
```

That's the code I have, it works fine for filling the entire height of the window and using available space until the images are added to the code.

They should be a fixed size and content should be within that DIV only. Am I missing another piece of code for height?

The images should also be horizontally and vertically centred within their respective DIV containers.

Comment: Using the html-attribute `height`, especially with percentages, can have mixed results.  Instead try adding it in your css, i.e. `style="height: 5%;"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img `width` and `height` however, only pixels are acceptable. Also `bgcolor` is deprecated.

Comment: @Kunukn that's no help at all. I need to use percentages so that it also scales for mobile. Both DIV containers are the correct size before the images are added.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to set limits on the height and width regardless of their content, then place specific `max-height` and `max-width` AND set their `height` and width to `100%`. I suggest you create a general class (I made a class called `card`) and put all the constant stuff there.

1. I used [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on class `card` to make sure the contents fit nicely inside.
2. I set max-height and max-width on the images to make them consistent. One downside to this is if you use different sized images than your max-height and max-width (like I did in my code snippet below), they will be distorted, scaled, etc.

```html
<div class="card white">
<img class="welcome" src="http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/small-kitten-meowing.jpg" alt="Welcome">
</div>

<div class="card orange">
<p>Welcome!</p>
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none">
    <img class="launch" src="https://d4n5pyzr6ibrc.cloudfront.net/media/27FB7F0C-9885-42A6-9E0C19C35242B5AC/4785B1C2-8734-405D-96DC23A6A32F256B/thul-90efb785-97af-5e51-94cf-503fc81b6940.jpg?" alt="Logo1">
</div>

<div class="card green">
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none">
    <img class="launch" src="https://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg" alt="Logo2">
</div>

<style>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
} 

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
} 

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`height: 5%` would actually mean 5% of the parent element - is that what you want? If instead you want the height to be 5% of the *window*, you can use `height: 5vh`  (= 5% of the viewport height).

For the centering, you can add `display: flex` and additional properties (see snippet below) to the three elements (however, this will also affect the one paragraph in the second DIV)

And note a few other settings: Image wrapped int `p` tag in the second element to NOT be in one line with the `p` above it etc.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.white,
.orange,
.green {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 45%;
  width: 100%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 45%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 5vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <div class="white">
    <img class="welcome" src="http://placehold.it/300x200/ddd" alt="Welcome">
  </div>

  <div class="orange">
    <p>Welcome!</p>
    <p>
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
        <img class="launch" src="http://placehold.it/300x200/ddd" alt="Logo1"></a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="green">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
      <img class="launch" src="http://placehold.it/300x200/ddd" alt="Logo2"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think so. I completely forgot about using vh for viewport height. How would I set each image's height in line because not all of them will be the same size. could I set the height using width="5%". I don't want all images to be the same size if that makes sense.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. You can of course use pixel values for sizes in order to have different sizes. And I would not set size values for both height AND width, but define of of these two as `auto`, which will help to keep the image proportions (width to height)

Comment: I figured it out, I think. You said;

img {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 5vh;
}

That would apply to all images, I would need to be able to set a different size for each individual image.

Comment: well, so just assign classes or IDs to your img tags and set up different rules (with different sizes) for these classes or IDs